# Input number on firefox doesn't works correctly

Tags: html, angular, user-input

In my angular 4 application I am using some input type=number, but in firefox I can write letters and this isn't what I want.
Why firefox allows this? Is there a way to make it works also in firefox because in chrome works perfectly.
 this is my input field:

```
<label class="control-label">inserttickets <span class="star">*</span>
</label> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="blockFrom"
required [(ngModel)]="blockFrom" min="1" name="blockFrom"
#BlockFrom="ngModel">
```

I found some old discussions about that but maybe now there are some solutions?

Comment: make use of validators in this case , this is a firefox bug i hope

Comment: I think it has some logic. It doesn't prevent the user entering whatever she wishes but will trigger the invalid state if it's not the expected type. And it expects you write a validator. I always do and never use "number" , "text" only.

Comment: Also, even in chrome, with my 'azerty' keyboard I can still enter 'e'  in number type of input